# Doctrine Query Result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine

I do have the following Doctrine query. My database is a MySQL.

```
    public static function getLastList($user_id){

    $user_id = 123;

    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('list l')
            ->innerJoin('l.listUser lu ')
            ->where('lu.user_id = ?', $user_id)
            ->orderBy('e.created ASC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->execute();

    if ($q == NULL) {
        print_r('false');
    } else {
        print_r('not false');
    }
}
```

I don't have a entry in my database with the user_id = 123. So what I expect is a "false". But "not false" is the result.

1.) Why?

2.) How can I divide with this specific query beteween "Yes, there ist a user" or "No, there is no user"?

Thanks!

Gunnar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`execute()`](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Doctrine_Query_Abstract.class.html#det_methods_execute) returns `Doctrine_Collection`

You can check collection's size by calling [`count()`](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Doctrine_Collection.class.html#det_methods_count)

```
if ($q->count() == 0) {
    print_r('false');
} else {
    print_r('not false');
}
```

Comment: And $q.count() or $q->count() doesn't? I'm not sure that count($q) is what you really need.

Comment: Why isn't it really what I need?

Comment: As far as I know it is not documented way to get Doctrine_Collection's items count. If it is really so (not documented) it may work wrong in some cases or not work at all in future versions.